# Is there a way to "reset" Advanced Data Protection secured iCloud accounts when locked out?

Tags: icloud, security, privacy, apple-id

I'm considering activating Advanced Data Protection for iCloud.

As part of activating it, it seems like I need to enable either a recovery key or a recovery contact. Also, according to Apple's [documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec973254c5f/web), there is no way to regain access to most iCloud data in case I lose access to both, as well as to a trusted device currently logged in to my iCloud account.

That's fine/expected: I have backups, and worst case I can start over with my user data.

However, what I've been wondering is whether there is actually such a way to "start over" at all:

Will Apple even let me log back into a recovery key protected account without that key, under the condition that all previous data is wiped, just like it works for iCloud Keychain (where they give me that option in case I can't provide a previous device's passcode)?

Or will the account be permanently lost, like Apple also seems to hint at in the [documentation for iCloud recovery keys](https://support.apple.com/en-us/109345)? In that case, what would happen to all my iTunes purchases, access to my Apple Card invoices etc. – are these gone as well?

Comment: Are you asking how you might reset your account password once you enable this?